# why i cant make this series by C code

Tags: c, series

I tried to write Series below in C:
series : `(1^1),(2^(1/2)),(6^(1/4)),(24^(1/8)),...,((n!)^((1/2)^n))`.

C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int fact(int x){
  if (x==1)
    return 1;
    else return x*fact(x-1);
}


int main(){
    int x,y;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    y=x;
    x=fact(x);
    y=pow(0.5,y-1);
    double h;
    h=pow(x,y);
    printf("\n%lf" ,h);
    return 0;
}
```

Why it's print `1.00000` all the time?

Comment: You've used the Engineer's Series Convention: All infinite series converge, and specifically they converge to the first term. This is usually correct to within the usual margin of error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the variable `y` is `int`, so storing the return value of `pow()` in it truncates. Read [the manual page for `pow()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow).

Please check how you enable all warnings in your compiler, and *look at the compiler output*.

Comment: Good to say that `pow` returns a `double`

Comment: @AlterMann True, that doesn't hurt. I added a link.

Comment: my IDE is devc++ and the compiler is GCC, how to enable warnings in it?!

Answer (score 2):

Function `pow(a,b)` takes `double` as argument and returns `double`. Try to replace `int` with `double`.